# Fiber channel HBA, backwards compatibility

Tags: lsi, fibre-channel, hba

I'm pretty new to using FC HBA's, but planning on expanding my server with a storrage array.
I found a cheap older (but good enough for my use case) LSI Engenio 1932.
It has dual 4Gbs FC connection.

I already got an unused LPE12002 HBA laying around that i thought of using.
Now the LPE12002 has dual 8Gbs FC, so would that work with the 4Gbs FC on the LSI array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 99% change it will work (not 100% as I didn't see it personally). Engenio controllers typically have short wave interfaces and support both arbirtated loop and point-to-point topologies. Looking at the HBA spec, it should work. In terms of frequency it can negotiate down to 4 and even to 2 Gbps.